# Fullcalendar V5 : dayHeaders are not visible in resourceTimeGridDay view

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

`dayHeaders` are visible in `resourceTimeGridWeek` view. See the screenshot below.

[image]

`dayHeaders` are not visible in `resourceTimeGridDay` view. See the screenshot below.

[image]

How can I show the `dayHeaders` in `resourceTimeGridDay` view also same as the `resourceTimeGridWeek` view?

Note: Fullcalendar `V5(version 5)`, using `resourceTimeGrid` plugin (`'@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid'`).

Comment: Why would you need to display the day header? It's only showing one day, and the date is already there in the main title. The reason the day headers don't show in the day view is because they're unnecessary.

Comment: @ADyson, Just check the `TimeGrid View`. It showing the day header for single view too. Refer : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timegrid-standard-view-demo. That's why I tried to show that. Actually that is the requirement that I should develop.

Comment: Ok, yes it does. But actually it's still redundant. Why do you think you need this, exactly? The date is already shown right above it. If you want it to include the day of the week, you can change the format settings for it.

Comment: Anyway I can't see any way to get the header back into the resourceTimeGridDay view by using the settings, so if you _really_ want it, you'd have to add it in with custom code I think - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-header-render-hooks

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, If I able to get this done planned to remove header title, that is the requirement. anyway, thanks for the support.